# REDIRECT FAILED

Tags: angular, angular-router

I try to realize a login page using angular and app-routing but the rediction is not done, it passes in the url but the html code remains the same.
this is de code of the app-routing-module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ChooseCatalogueComponent } from './choose-catalogue/choose- 
catalogue.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'choose-catalogue', component: ChooseCatalogueComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

login.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(private router: Router) { }
        ngOnInit() {
        }

    login() : void {
        if(this.username =='admin' && this.password == 'admin'){

            this.router.navigate(["choose-catalogue"]);
            }
        else {
            this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
        }   
    }
}
```

when I enter the login and password as "admin/admin" the URL of the page changes to http://localhost:4200/choose-catalogue, but html remains that of the login page

Comment: Any errors in the console ? Please provide a [mcve] of your issue

Comment: @trichetriche no errors raised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take out the `/` in the `router.navigate`

```
 this.router.navigate(["login"]);
```

Comment: thank you @Matheus it's work after adding router-outlet  as you told me